# How to query this new CalendarEvent property names exceptionOccurrences?

Tags: calendar, microsoft-graph-api, office365

Microsoft graph beta end point exposed a new property on the Calendar Event entity for series master id type. Documentation says

"Contains the id property values of the event instances that are exceptions in a recurring series.
Exceptions can differ from other occurrences in a recurring series, such as the subject, start or end times, or attendees. Exceptions do not include cancelled occurrences.

Returned only on $select and $expand in a GET operation which specifies the id of a series master event (that is, the seriesMasterId property value)."

I am running this query but still don't see the above property, What am I missing?

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/events/AAMkADljY2EwNjU2LWVhYTItNDlmMy05ZWE1LTA5Zjc5YzhhZTMyYwBGAAAAAAAJYBHio4VlTKwYgFRcz_44BwC0bqbZ5NLFRoWa_zAJHejIAAAAAAENAABqBW9?$select=subject,body,bodyPreview,organizer,attendees,start,end,location,cancelledOccurrences,exceptionOccurrences

Answer (score 2):

According to [example in official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-4-expand-a-series-master-event) for beta API you're missing `$expand=exceptionOccurrences` so your URL should be:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/events/AAMkADljY2EwNjU2LWVhYTItNDlmMy05ZWE1LTA5Zjc5YzhhZTMyYwBGAAAAAAAJYBHio4VlTKwYgFRcz_44BwC0bqbZ5NLFRoWa_zAJHejIAAAAAAENAABqBW9?$select=subject,body,bodyPreview,organizer,attendees,start,end,location,cancelledOccurrences,exceptionOccurrences&$expand=exceptionOccurrences
```

Note that current example in the official docs may still contain some editing errors (e.g. missing `&` that separates query string parameters).

Comment: Anyway, I've run into exactly the same issue as described [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/7947#issuecomment-685842197) and couldn't get working result even though I was following the documentation and error notes in the [merge thread](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/7947#issuecomment-685941990). One of developers commented that it "works for him" and pointed me to SO for help. So here we are...